# Access VBA - search Excel Sheet1 column A for value and put a corresponding value in column B?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In VBA, I created a `Collection` named C that looks like this:

```
Key      Item
Thing1   12
Thing2   15
Thing4   7
Thing6   3
```

In my Excel file, Sheet1 looks like this:

```
A        B
Thing1
Thing2
Thing3
Thing4
Thing5
Thing6
```

I'd like to look at each Key in C, search column A, and if found put the Item in column B. The result would be:

```
A        B
Thing1   12
Thing2   15
Thing3
Thing4   7
Thing5
Thing6   3
```

I initially thought I would do this by looping thru the Collection, getting the Key, searching for a match in "A:A", and then setting "B#" to the Item value .. just not sure on the syntax. After reading more, I don't think the `Key` value can be accessed.

```
Dim Count as Integer
Dim ItemToFind as String
Dim i as Integer

For Count = 1 to C.Count
    ItemToFind = C.Key(count) 'I don't think C.Key is a valid thing
    for i = 1 to 50 'there are less than 50 rows in Sheet1 to look thru        
        If Cells("A" & i).Value = ItemToFind Then
            Cells("B" & i).Value = C.Key(count)
        End If
    Next i
Next Count
```

I'm thinking maybe I need to create a new `Class` instead of using a `Collection`? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I'm trying to use a `Dictionary` object. I'm able to add things to the Dictionary and able to retrieve a Key, but get a Run-time error when checking if an Excel cell value = Dictionary Key.

I have a Dictionary named "dict" and loaded it up with Keys and Values with this:

```
dict.Add Key:=Thing, Item:=TotalThings
```

I'm using this code to loop thru the Dictionary items and see if they exist in Column A in the worksheet:

```
Dim Count as Integer
Dim KeyToFind as String
Dim i as Integer

For Count = 1 to dict.Count
    KeyToFind = dict.Keys(count)

    For i = 1 To 50
        If oExcel.Worksheets(1).Cells("A" & i).Value = KeyToFind Then
            oExcel.Worksheets(1).Cells("B" & i).Value = dict.Item(Count)
        End If
    Next i
Next Count
```

On `If oExcel.Worksheets(1).Cells("A" & i).Value = KeyToFind Then` I get a Run-time error 1004: Application-definded or object-defined error. If I hover over KeyToFind in debug mode, it does contain the first Key in the Dictionary.

Comment: You tagged your question with Access, but you're talking about an Excel sheet. Are you doing this in Access or Excel? or controlling an Excel file thru an Access db?

Comment: Also, you are right. `.Key()` is not valid method. You can try `.item()` instead, but that requires the uniquekey so you can't really use it the way you intend here., i.e. `debug.print c.item("thing1")` would return 12

Comment: @PowerUser - the VBA is in Access, but it's opening an Excel file

Comment: add a line right above your error and try `msgbox oExcel.Worksheets(1).Cells("A" & i).Value`. Does it return the values you expect??

Comment: @PowerUser - I tried that, and get the same Run-time error. I guess I'm not addressing a specific cell properly. I'll check it out .. thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Looks like the proper syntax for what I'm trying to do is `msgbox oExcel.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value`

Comment: But `i` is the row number, right?  So shouldn't that be `Cells(i, 1)`?

Comment: You're right .. I had that backwards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made the wise choice by switching from a collection to a dictionary.  A dictionary has an `.Exists` method which should be useful.  Consider this snippet.

```vb
Dim dct As Object
Set dct = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dct.Add "Thing1", 12
dct.Add "Thing2", 15
dct.Add "Thing4", 7
dct.Add "Thing6", 3
Debug.Print dct.Exists("BogusThing") ' returns False
```

Then you could use `dct.Exists` with each column A value in the sheet ... if that key exists in the dictionary, store the matching value to column B.

This may not be exactly correct, but hopefully it's close enough to get you started.

```vb
Const lngRows As Long = 50
Dim objSheet As Object
Dim strKey As String

Set objSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1) ' you know where oExcel comes from
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To lngRows
    'strKey = objSheet.Cells("A" & i).value ' oops
    strKey = objSheet.Cells(i, 1).value
    If dct.Exists(strKey) Then
        'objSheet.Cells("B" & i).value = dct(strKey) ' oops again
        objSheet.Cells(i, 2).value = dct(strKey)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean code :) I tweaked it slightly .. instead of using lngRows = 50, I'm getting the number of actual rows with `LastRow = oSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`. I've actually done something similar to this in C# using Dictionary.ContainsKey .. never thought to see if there was something similar in VBA! Thanks again!